# Why is Bundler unable to fetch gem metadata?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, fedora

So very new to rails. I managed to install *ruby* and then *rails framework* on *Fedora 17*.

Here are the summary of steps I did to install ruby and rails framework:

1. `yum install make openssh-clients gcc libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel python-devel`
2. `sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)`
3. `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
4. `rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290 --with-openssl`
5. `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default`
6. `rvm all do gem update --system`
7. `rvm all do gem install rails`

Well.. So far so good.. Just wanted to test if the installation was perfect. 
I created a hello world sample (*test.rb*) to test ruby installation

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "hello World"
```

and running this with `./test.rb` it works fine.

Now when I was test rails framework installation by creating a new project using

```
rails new demo
```

I receive the error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

What am I missing here? Or what have I done additionally which I was not suppose to do?
Looked into https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md. Could not figure out. Has anyone come across similar issue and found a way to deal with it?

Comment: Figuring out the problem.. May soon find an answer..

Comment: Are you getting any other error messages before or after the Bundler fatal error message?

Comment: nothing else before or after the error message.

Comment: Is the openssl package installed on your system?

Comment: Yes.. openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.0j-1.fc17 is installed

Comment: What is your rails version?. Please put this command in terminal "rails -v"

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have these packages installed...

`git-core curl make bzip2 gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel libxslt-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl openssl-devel`

You might want to check out this blog [post](http://jaysonrowe.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-ruby-and-rails-on-fedora.html) to see if it helps you at all.

Comment: Seems like few more extensions are missing.. Will update the post soon.

Comment: It is not the problem with openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.0j-1.fc17

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode 4.1 by any chance? Seems like a lot of people have run into bundler issues after upgrading to Lion (but neglecting to upgrade Xcode as well...).

As in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753000/nokogiri-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension).