# Testing a Rails app without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have a Rails app (Rails - 2.3.8, Linux) which uses a MySQL database, but the database is generated separately (not through the Rails migration), so I would like to know

How can I implement testing on this application (please note currently there are no test suit at all)?

I would prefer not to have a database at all and test the functionality (including ActiveRecord models through the unit test) (because it will make the test suit independent as I see).

Currently I found this gem (temping - https://github.com/jpignata/temping) via a Stack Overflow link itself.

Please let me know if I'm going in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great resource on one method of TDD using RSpec which is more powerful than unit testing imo.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test

If you are avoiding using MySQL you could simply specify Sqlite3 in your Database.yaml file:

```
test:
adapter: sqlite3
encoding: unicode
database: gc_test
pool: 5
```

Be sure to include Gem:

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby'
```

If you have having trouble with this install, checkout this question:
[Why can't I install the SQLite gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421225/why-cant-i-install-the-sqlite-gem)

Comment: Hi @hagope, thanks for the answer, but I guess even to use sqlite3, I need to have a schema.rb file to load the database, but in my case, my db folder is empty. so I guess I cant use sqlite3, please correct me if I'm wrong,

Comment: I ended up dumping the existing schema and creating the test database