# cant bundle rails app.sqlite3 failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, cygwin, bundle

it says

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/Fash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/local/include
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/Fash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --enable-local
        --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /home/Fash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Fash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

i am using cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in compilation of required libraries to install sqlite3.
Check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421225/why-cant-i-install-the-sqlite-gem) for steps to solve this.